# How can I use GROUP BY & MAX() in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have requirement to prepare a report based on final outcomes like LVL, QT_ID and PRODUCT.

I have to following condition are

1. Needs to group by QT_ID and PRODUCT.
2. the MAX(LVL) of each QT_ID is LVL for each QT_ID and PRODUCT group.

Input values are below

```
 -----------------------------
  LVL        QT_ID     PRODUCT    
 -----------------------------
   2          Q1       P1
   3          Q1       P2
   8          Q2       P1
   9          Q2       P2
 -----------------------------
```

Expected result is below

```
 -----------------------------
  LVL        QT_ID     PRODUCT    
 -----------------------------
   3          Q1       P1
   3          Q1       P2
   9          Q2       P1
   9          Q2       P2
 -----------------------------
```

I tried SQL Query

```
  SELECT MAX(LVL), QT_ID, PRODUCT FROM TMP_TEMP GROUP BY QT_ID, PRODUCT
```

My query's result is below

```
 -----------------------------
  LVL        QT_ID     PRODUCT    
 -----------------------------
   2          Q1       P1
   8          Q2       P1
   3          Q1       P2
   9          Q2       P2
 -----------------------------
```

anyone can help me to get expected output using above data?

Note: I do not use sub-query or join query.

Comment: the max(LVL) of each QT_ID is LVL for each QT_ID and PRODUCT group

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
SELECT t2.LVL, t1.QT_ID, t1.PRODUCT
FROM TMP_TEMP t1 
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT QT_ID,MAX(LVL) as LVL
FROM TMP_TEMP 
GROUP BY QT_ID
) t2 on t1.QT_ID=t2.QT_ID
```

Comment: I do not use sub-query or join-query, becoz We are using a very old tool to generate dynamic query

Comment: your query is working fine in Oracle client. thanks and giving one up vote to your's try.